# How can I make a firefox add-on contentscript inject and run a script before other page scripts?

Tags: firefox-addon, content-script, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm working on a Browser extension/add-on. We have it working in Chrome, so I'm trying to get it working in Firefox.

I've gotten my add-on to load in Firefox Developer Edition 49.0a2 (2016-07-25).

My extension involves a content_script set to `run_at: document_start`, so it can inject a script tag before other page scripts run, so it can make an object globally available to websites.

This has seemed to work fine in Chrome, but in Firefox it has proven to be a bit of a race condition, with other page resources loading first most of the time.

Is there a strategy to load a content script in a way that it can inject & load a script before any other page scripts run?

When I add logs, I can isolate what is happening pretty nicely.  In this example content-script:

```
// inject in-page script
console.log('STEP 1, this always happens first')
var scriptTag = document.createElement('script')
scriptTag.src = chrome.extension.getURL('scripts/inpage.js')
scriptTag.onload = function () { this.parentNode.removeChild(this) }
var container = document.head || document.documentElement
// append as first child
container.insertBefore(scriptTag, container.children[0])
```

Now if the file `scripts/inpage.js` simply runs a log, like

```
console.log('STEP 2, this should always run second')
```

And I visit a page with a script like this:

```
console.log('Step 3, the page itself, should run last')
```

In practice, Step 2 and Step 3 run in a non-deterministic order.

Thanks a lot!

I have Firefox-compatible version of the script in a public repository on a special branch if you dare to try it yourself: https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-plugin/tree/FirefoxCompatibility

Comment: This is the line where I prepend a script tag into the current page. When I do this with logs, I do see this code run before the page script, but the injected script itself does not always run before the page scripts. https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-plugin/blob/FirefoxCompatibility/app/scripts/contentscript.js#L20

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An dynamically inserted script with an external source (`<script src>`) does not block the execution of scripts, so there is no guarantee that your script would load. If your extension worked in Chrome, it was just by sheer luck.

If you really want to run some script before the rest, you have to run it inline:

```js
var actualCode = `
// Content of scripts/inpage.js here
`;

var s = document.createElement('script');
s.textContent = actualCode;
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
s.remove();
```

Ideally, your build script would read `scripts/inpage.js`, serialize it to a string and put it in the `actualCode` variable. But if `inpage.js` is just a few lines of code, then the above can be used.

Note that you **should not** inject code in the web page unless it is absolutely necessary. The reason for that is that the execution environment of the page is untrusted. If you inject at `document_start`, then you can save functions and (prototype) methods that use for later (in a closure), but very careful coding is required.

If your content script is not generated by a build script and you still want to keep the scripts separate, then you can also use synchronous `XMLHttpRequest` to fetch the script. Synchronous XHR is deprecated for performance reasons, so use it at your own risk. Extension code is typically bundled with your extension, so the use of sync xhr should be low-risk:

```js
// Note: do not use synchronous XHR in production!
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open('GET', chrome.runtime.getURL('scripts/inpage.js'), false);
x.send();
var actualCode = x.responseText;

var s = document.createElement('script');
s.textContent = actualCode;
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
s.remove();
```

Comment: I'll just add a note that in IRC you also pointed out that FireFox provides additional ways to cleanly accomplish my goals of exposing an API to the main page from a contentscript, via the export helpers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Language_Bindings/Components.utils.exportFunction

Comment: @DanF `Component.utils.exportFunction`, etc. are not yet available (and they will **not** become available at the `Components` namespace; WebExtensions **cannot** use `Components`). When the patch at https://bugzil.la/1280482 lands, you can get the same functionality using the global `exportFunction` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a bootstrap.js based addon you can use a framescript and `DOMWindowCreated` to work with the document before even the HTML DOM (past basics of document.body etc) renders - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox/Frame_script_environment#Events - the innerHTML will be available but no script would have executed. You can put your inline script at the top as @Rob mentioned.